# Java Script создание параллельных потоков

Tags: javascript, многопоточность

Создаю космическую стрелялку в браузере на JS и у меня есть булыжники которые летят на корабль, есть звезды которые так же двигаются ко космосу и имеется корабль который может стрелять и разрушать булыжники.

Хотелось бы узнать как можно реализовать перемещение звезд и булыжников в параллельном потоке, чтобы они каждую секунду передвигались и не блокировали основной поток?

Comment: @Drakonoved и как тогда реализовать перемещение булыжников, звезд, если нет отдельных потоков? Если реализовывать в основном потоке через вечный цикл то будет блокироваться интерфейс, а мне нужно еще считывать и нажатие кнопок игроком.

Comment: setTimeout, setInterval, requestAnimationFrame

Comment: почитайте про webWorker

Comment: @ИльяАнтипанов, а зачем тебе отдельные потоки?

Comment: @Grundy чтобы можно было запускать передвижение фоновых объектов, игровых объектов и не терять при этом управление, но выше уже предложили решение моей проблемы это "setTimeout, setInterval, requestAnimationFrame", жаль что потоков конечно нет в JS, но мою проблему и данные методы могут решить

Answer (score 0):

В целом вот, можно все события обрабатывать в одном единственном потоке:

```js
let allStones = [];
let allBullets = [];

function object(parent, use, x, y, dirx, diry) {
    let id = 'obj_' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
    parent.innerHTML += `<use id="${id}" xlink:href="#${use}" />`;
    return {
        id, dirx, diry, x, y, t: Date.now(),
        move: function(t) {
            let dt = (t - this.t)/1000; // sec
            this.t = t;
            let x = this.x += dt*this.dirx;
            let y = this.y += dt*this.diry;
            let el = document.getElementById(id);
            if (Math.abs(x) > 251 || Math.abs(y) > 251)
                return el.remove();
            el.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${x},${y})`);
            return true
        }
    }
}

let pt = svg.createSVGPoint();

function cursorPoint(e) {
    pt.x = e.clientX; 
    pt.y = e.clientY;
    return pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}

addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    var p = cursorPoint(e);
    player.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${p.x},${p.y})`);
})

addEventListener('click', e => {
    var p = cursorPoint(e);
    allBullets.push(object(bullets, 'bullet', 
            p.x, p.y-15, Math.random()*20-10, -500));
})

requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);

function drawFrame() {
    requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);

    if (Math.random()>0.99) 
        allStones.push(object(stones, 'stone', 
            Math.random()*500 - 250, -250, Math.random()*40-20, 100));
    
    let t = Date.now();  
    allStones = allStones.filter(s => s.move(t));
    allBullets = allBullets.filter(b => b.move(t));

    allBullets = allBullets.filter(b => {
        let result = true;
        allStones = allStones.filter(s => {
            let dx = b.x-s.x;
            let dy = b.y-s.y;
            let res = dx*dx + dy*dy > 100;
            if (!res) {
                result = false;
                document.getElementById(s.id).remove();
                score.innerHTML = +score.innerHTML + 1
            }
            return res;
        });
        if (!result)
             document.getElementById(b.id).remove();
        return result;
    });
}
```

```css
svg {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  cursor: none;
  user-select:none;
}
```

```html
<svg id=svg viewbox="-250,-250,500,500">
    <defs>
      <circle id="bullet" r=3 fill="wheat" />
      <circle id="stone" r=10 fill="gray" />
    </defs>
    <text id=score y=-235 fill=white text-align="middle">0</text>
    <g id=game>
        <g id=player transform=translate(250,450)>
            <path d="M-10,0l9,-10l1,-5l1,5l9,10" fill="steelblue"/>
        </g>
        <g id=bullets></g>
        <g id=stones></g>
    </g>
</svg>
```